# Jira Service Desk Installation

Tags: jira

I want to install Jira Service Desk in a Server.

After reading Atlassian Documentation I have some doubts concerning Jira Service Desk installation.

To install Jira Service Desk (Server), do I have to install Jira Software before doing it or both of them are different products who can be installed without having to install the other?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843264/jira-and-sql-server-2014-connection), Technically JIRA ServiceDesk is a plugin on top of JIRA Software or Core. You can download ServiceDesk as a release as well but it will install JIRA and enable ServiceDesk by default. As a best practice I always install JIRA and then enable ServiceDesk on top of it.